# How to remove spaces around "is equal to" while providing input using python

Tags: python

I have a query which will be given as an argument which contains key value pairs.

```
query = "index=sai age=xx rep=yes"
```

Sometimes spaces will be provided after keys or before values as below, Need some help to trim spaces around "is equal to" and print the query.

```
query = "index =sai age=xx rest= curl"
```

desired result to be printed:

```
index=sai sss=xyz rest=curl
```

Comment: `re.sub(r"( )*=( )*", "=", query)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regular expression

```
import re
i="index =sai age=xx rest= curl"
o=re.sub("\s+=|=\s+", "=", i)
print(o)
```

Gives you:

```
index=sai age=xx rest=curl
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. It worked. But when I tried the below I'm not getting the output as expected.

i="index =sai age = xx rest= curl"

output=re.sub("\s+=|=+\s|\s+=+\s", "=", i)

>>> print output
index=sai age= xx rest=curl

Comment: To remove `" = "` from the strings as well use this regex:

`\s+=\s+|\s+=|=\s+`

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> s = 'index =sai age=xx rest= curl'
>>> s.replace(' =', '=')
'index=sai age=xx rest= curl'
>>> s.replace('= ', '=')
'index =sai age=xx rest=curl'
```

OR

```
>>> s.replace('= ', '=').replace('= ', '=')
'index =sai age=xx rest=curl'
```